# What is Unity (Application Block) resolving?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, log4net

I want to do something like this:

```
        container.RegisterType<ILog>(new InjectionFactory(
            ctr =>
            {
                return LogManager.GetLogger( "HOW CAN I PASS WHAT UNITY IS RESOLVING HERE?");
            }));
```

When there's a unity resolution error, there's usually a hint about which object Unity was resolving when it failed. How can I get to that context under normal scenario?

Comment: Can you please give more details? Are you trying to pass the type in which `ILog` was injected? Please give an example.

Comment: Yes - exactly. So this way I can have Unity instantiate the logger and the class doesn't need to know about it.